# Phonegap Eclipse plugin similar to Applaud

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

Does anybody know a plugin similar to Applaud for fast Android Phonegap developing?
Applaud is very good but the last supported Phonegap version is 1.9, they didn't update it since then and I need at least Phonegap 2.1 for an app.
Thank you and I'm waiting for your recommendations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [download PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/download/) to a local folder. Then when creating a project do not use the Applaud built-in PhoneGap, instead point it to your PhoneGap download folder, like shown below:

[image: custom location for phonegap]

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this before with 2.4 and gave me an error but with 2.5 it's working fine.

Comment: Just for future users with questions, I had to use 2.9.0 not 2.9.1 when doing this. 2.9.1 gave errors when entering the path.